# How to insert in your base using parameters from different Views in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

I am using also Entity Framework and Code First Method.

I have a view which contains a PartialView. That's mean when i click on a button in my view, the partial view appears.

The view (Index.aspx) and the partialview (Gestion.ascx) contains DropDownList and TextBox to fill out with values that will be saved in a table 'Gamme' in my base.

This is the View 'Index.aspx':

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Anouar"))
   { %>
  <div><%:Html.Label("Gamme :")%><%: Html.DropDownList("SelectedProfile_Ga", new SelectList(Model.Profile_GaItems, "ID_Gamme", "ID_Gamme"))%> <input type="button" value="Configurer" id="btnShowGestion" /></div> 




<div id="divGestion"><%: Html.Partial("Gestion", Model) %></div>
       <% } %>   
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {

                //                $('#divGestion').load('/Anouar/Gestion');



                $('#btnShowGestion').click(function () { $('#divGestion').slideToggle("slow") });



            });

</script>

</asp:Content>
```

and this is the Controller that populate the view 'Index' :

```
public class ProfileGaController : Controller
    {
        private GammeContext db = new GammeContext();

        //
        // GET: /ProfileGa/
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index(Profile_Ga profile_ga, Poste poste)
        {

            var viewModel = new FlowViewModel();
            viewModel.PostesItems = new SelectList(db.Postes.ToList(), "ID_Poste", "ID_Poste"); 
            //viewModel.PostesItems = db.Postes.ToList() ?? new List<Poste>();
               viewModel.Profile_GaItems = db.Profil_Gas.ToList();
               viewModel.GaItems = db.Gammes.ToList();

            return View(viewModel);



        }
```

and this is the Partial View 'Gestion.ascx' :

```
<fieldset class="parametrage">
        <legend>Gestion de Gamme</legend>

        <div><%:Html.Label("Poste :")%><%: Html.DropDownList("SelectedPoste", Model.PostesItems)%><input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="Poste Initial" id= "chkMain" onclick="test();"/>Poste Initial<input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="Poste Final" id= "chkFirst" onclick="test2();"/>Poste Final</div>


         <div><%:Html.Label("Nombre de Passage :")%><%: Html.EditorFor(x=>x.YourGammeModel.Nbr_Passage)%></div>
        <div><%:Html.Label("Position :")%><%: Html.EditorFor(x=>x.YourGammeModel.Position)%></div>
        <div><%:Html.Label("Poste Précédent :")%><%: Html.DropDownList("PostePrecedentSelected", Model.PostesItems)%></div>
        <div><%:Html.Label("Poste Suivant :")%><%: Html.DropDownList("PosteSuivantSelected", Model.PostesItems)%></div>
        <div><input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" id="btnSave"  /></div>

        </fieldset>
```

and this is the Controller which populate the PartialView :

```
public class AnouarController : Controller
    {

         private GammeContext db = new GammeContext();


        //
        // GET: /Anouar/

         public ActionResult Gestion(FlowViewModel model)
         {

             model.YourGammeModel = new Gamme();
             return PartialView(model);

         }

         [HttpPost]
         public ActionResult Create(FlowViewModel model)
         {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                db.Gammes.Add(model.YourGammeModel);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Gestion");  
            }


            return View(model.YourGammeModel);
        }
    }
```

And Finally this is The ViewModel that contains the attributs :

```
public class FlowViewModel
    {

        [Key]
        public string IDv { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public SelectList PostesItems { get; set; }

        public List<Profile_Ga> Profile_GaItems { get; set; }
        public List<Gamme> GaItems { get; set; }

        public Gamme YourGammeModel { get; set; }

        public int SelectedProfile_Ga { get; set; }

        public int SelectedGamme{ get; set; }

        public int SelectedPoste { get; set; }

        public int PostePrecedentSelected { get; set; } 
        public int PosteSuivantSelected { get; set; }        
    }
```

When I execute my code, this is error appear always :

> The view 'Create' or its master was not found or no view engine
>   supports the searched locations. The following locations were
>   searched: ~/Views/Anouar/Create.aspx ~/Views/Anouar/Create.ascx
>   ~/Views/Shared/Create.aspx ~/Views/Shared/Create.ascx
>   ~/Views/Anouar/Create.cshtml ~/Views/Anouar/Create.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Create.cshtml ~/Views/Shared/Create.vbhtml
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.

This is a screenshot concerning the values of model when i put a breakpoint at the function Create :
[image: pic]

Comment: is there a reason your using depricated .aspx and .ascx instead of razor code in an MVC 3 app?

Comment: yes because the template that i am using doesn't work only with aspx or ascx

Comment: By executing do you mean submitting the form? If yes, I'm guessing you're getting that error because `ModelState` isn't valid or else `model.YourGammeModel` is not what your view is expecting.

Comment: yes executing means submitting the form ! I don't know,,,I will try with a breakpoint and give you result

Comment: @MattSull87 please check my update,,, I put a screenshot concerning the values of model  at the function Create

Comment: @ScottSelby - ASPX and ASCX are not deprecated.

Comment: @MystereMan do you have an idea please about the problem,,,I am really stuck ! and I got no answers

Comment: @anouar - No, because I cannot understand your question.  Your entire question makes no sense to me.

Comment: @MystereMan Ok I will explain more and if anything is not clear just ask me,,,,IT's Simple : I am trying to fill out a table in my base! the values will be taken from a form. (DropDownList + TextBox) 
The problem : The form is divided in 2 views. Clear until now ?

Comment: @anouar - No, the phrase "fill out a table in my base" makes no logical sense.  your base what?  What table? how is it filled out?  What kind of table?  Html table? SQL table?

Comment: @MystereMan First, sorry for the late,,I had a connexion problem
Second, fill out a table means INSERT Values in a Table in my base SQL
Exacltly like : INSERT INTO TABLE (VALUE 1,VALUE 2,...) but this is using Entity Framework if you have an idea abou it,,,,I am waiting your questions :)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the error you're getting is because `ModelState.IsValid` is false, so it's hitting

```
return View(model.YourGammeModel);
```

Since it's in a method called `Create` you haven't specified a view to return, it's looking for a view called Create, and not finding one, which is causing the error.

You need to either specify a view to return or make one called Create for this error to clear. Then you need to investigate why `ModelState.IsValid` is false.

Edit: And looking at it again, I'd suspect that `ModelState` isn't valid because you have the `[Key]` attribute on `IDv` and it's coming through as null.

Comment: yes your idea is right,,,I delete the test of ModelState,,,but now the ID_Gamme still null,,,this error appaer :
Can not insert the value NULL into column 'ID_Gamme' table 'Flux.dbo.Gamme'. This column does not accept NULL values. INSERT failed. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Is it the primary key for the table? If you're setting it manually you can do it when you declare `model.YourGammeModel = new Gamme();` by changing it to `new Gamme { ID_Gamme = whatever }`, or you can change your database settings to auto-generate an ID, depending on the datatype of `ID_Gamme`

Comment: No,,i can't generate automatically the ID_Gamme because it has been load from the table Profil_Ga.
So to resume : I have : ID_Gamme (loading from the table Profil_ga) + the rest of parameters (are load from table Poste)==> all this parametres must be recorded in table Gamme

Comment: So where you have `public ActionResult Index(Profile_Ga profile_ga, Poste poste)`, does that `profile_ga` have the ID in it?

Comment: public ActionResult Index(Profile_Ga profile_ga, Poste poste) is in the Profile_Ga Controller ,,,which populate the View Index (this is the view which i put the code above)
ID_Gamme is in the model Profile_Ga
But also I have a table in my base named 'Gamme' which its PK is compsed from 2FK (ID_Gamme from Profile_Ga) and (ID_Poste from Poste)

Comment: is that complicated ? need more explication??

Comment: It's getting beyond a bug and getting to be larger design issues. I'm heading offline for the night, try me later.

Comment: I am here now,,,if you have a time,,please let's correct the problem